# LinqToCsv - not all the rows are written to the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linqtocsv

I am using LinqToCsv to write data to a CSV file. 
I have a list of objects that has 8 number of records, however, when I write the csv to the MemoryStream and then to the disk it writes only 7 of them. The code is as follows

```cs
var csvClaims = GetCSVClaims(webUser, searchString, isReferenceSearch);
CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
CsvFileDescription outputFileDesc = new CsvFileDescription
{
   SeparatorChar = ',',
   FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
};
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(memStream);
cc.Write(csvClaims, tw, outputFileDesc);
return memStream.ToArray();
```

I am not sure what am I missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am not adding the CSVClaims class here as it is quite big but can be added if required.

Comment: This answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15438133/968301

Comment: This question would be very easy to answer if we had a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var csvClaims = GetCSVClaims(webUser, searchString, isReferenceSearch);
CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
CsvFileDescription outputFileDesc = new CsvFileDescription
{
    SeparatorChar = ',',
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
};
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var tw = new StreamWriter(memStream))
    {
        cc.Write(csvClaims, tw, outputFileDesc);
        tw.Flush();
        return memStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You need to flush the writer and dispose of your disposables.